# Tell me the way to use Django's models.FileField

Tags: python, django

I'm using models.FileField like this below.

[image]

It's a fantastic django function. Because, it makes user can upload within Django administration page without any code.

[image]

So, I clicked Part image url Link. But, I got a error message below.

[image]

my urls pattern is below.

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^parts/', include('parts.urls', namespace='parts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.MW_Hello.as_view(), name='Hello'),
]
```

Do I have to add url mapping in url patterns?

Comment: Are you clicking before or after you have clicked save? It's not actually saved and uploaded until then.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/

Comment: Can you show you settings.py

Comment: import os
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'parts',
)
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'MW_Service.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
...            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MW_Service.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
...   }
}
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)

Comment: You can update your answer with settings code? Comment is not a right place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your urls and settings for managing the static files

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/